# Avoid stretching of UIImage inside my UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm loading an UIImage UIImageView. The UIImageView has identical width and length, and when I load an UIImage it gets stretched.

Is there any way to load my UIImage inside my UIImageView without change in its proportions ?, I want the image to fit inside my UIImageView without deformation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set your imageview's `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`